# Linear Algebra Question: Change of Basis and Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Performing a change in basis/coordinates or similarity transformation entails matrix multiplication (multiplication between matrices).

But vector spaces only define scalar multiplication and vector addition only.

How do we reconcile this?

My background: studying control theory and its formulation through linear algebra

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn’t say performing a change of basis does not *entail* matrix multiplication; it only requires re-expressing an element in one basis as a linear combination of elements in another basis. Conveniently, a change of basis can be done via matrix multiplication, where the matrix coefficients depend on both the basis being transformed from and transformed to.

Comment: It's only when you start representing the vectors as column vectors with respect to a specific basis that you end up with a change of basis being a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a change of basis assigns to each basis vector another (not necessarily distinct) vector in the space, such that the output set is itself a basis. As this doesn't involve taking two vectors and returning a third via addition and scalar multiplication, this assignment isn't limited/affected by those operations. However, it *is* a function on the set of basis vectors which must extend to a function on the whole vector space and, therefore, must *respect* the operations. That is, a change of basis is a vector space automorphism (a linear bijection from, say, $V$ to $V$ which must send a basis to another basis).

Let $\vec{v} \in V$ be a vector. Fix a basis $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$, whence you have $\vec{v} = \sum_{i=1}^n e_iv^i = (e_1, \ldots e_n)\cdot (v^1, \ldots, v^n)^T$. Then a change of basis is equivalent to the choice of an  invertible $n \times n$ matrix $M$ via $\vec{v} = (e_1, \ldots, e_n)MM^{-1}(v^1, \ldots, v^n)^T = (\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_n)\cdot(\nu^1, \ldots, \nu^n)^T$. In this way, you can see that the change of basis is a function *defined by* scalar multiplication and addition (look at the resulting terms in the matrix multiplication), but $M \not\in V$ so there is no need to reconcile the product with there being a lack of a vector multiplication on $V$.